# Grpc code first JSON transcoding in .Net 7

Tags: c#, json, grpc

I am trying to add grpc json transcoding to my grpc code first project but can't seem to figure out on how to add that "option"

In the Microsoft demo the set the json transcoding as follows in the protobuf file

```
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/greeter/{name}"
    };
  }
}
```

In code first you have the following as an example as your protobuf but I can't seem to figure out how to add that option for the json transcoding

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IReportService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<ReportListResponse> Getreports(ProtoBuf.Grpc.CallContext context = default);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Currently, no: not supported. It is something we can consider as a future investment, but: everything is time :/](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/issues/264)

There is nothing stopping you from defining your services in proto files and then transcoding them but yeah that's a giant pain the arse if you have request or response schemas that are not very lightweight.

Comment: Please up vote the https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/issues/264 to make prioritize from owner of repo.

Comment: You do realize I provided a very clean workaround on that very issue right?